# Redis HashOperations delete all key

Tags: spring, redis

I use Spring Redis `HashOperations` to manipulate data on Redis. It requires 3 paramters: `key`, `haskkey` and `hashvalue`

Currently, I can only delete a hashkey by `HashOperations#delete(key, hashkey)`.
Is there anyway to delete all the hashkeys of a key other than iterating over all hashkeys ?

Comment: No. absolutely not.

Comment: You can delete the key, instead of the deleting hash keys one-by-one. When the key is deleted, all hash keys will be deleted.

Comment: can you give a brief of source code @for_stack

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I did use this one:

```
hashOperations
      .entries(key).keySet().forEach(haskKey->hashOperations.delete(key,haskKey));
```

Not proud of it, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I use `RedisTemplate<String, Set<RateDto>>` and `HashOperations<String, String, Set<RateDto>` and delete all like this:

```
redisTemplate.delete(KEY);
```